# std::map<const uint8_t, double>::find() warning from MISRA C++

Tags: c++, gcc, misra, qa-c

We have the following code:

```
class Foo {
    std::map<const uint8_t, double> m_throttle;
    // ...
    void bar(const uint8_t &msg_id)
    {
        if (m_throttle.find(msg_id) == m_throttle.end())
        {
            // Whatever
        }
    }
};
```

This produces the following error from the QA-C code checker when applying the MISRA C++ 2008 rules, highlighting the `msg_id` as the problematic token:

> 05-00-03  複合式が暗黙的に異なる本質型へ変換されています。

Or in English:

> Complex expressions are implicitly converted to different intrinsic types.

According to [the PDF here](https://www.grammatech.com/sites/default/files/misrac2008-mapping-broad.pdf), fuller text is:

> A cvalue expression shall not
>   be implicitly converted to a
>   different underlying type

However, the implementation of `std::map::find()` is just:

```
iterator
find(const key_type& __x)
{ return _M_t.find(__x); }
```

Where `key_type` should be `uint8_t`. Is this a bug in the tool, or is there something I am missing?

Note the tool uses the currently-installed `gcc`, apparently, which is 5.4.0.

Comment: Does switching to `m_throttle.cend()` affect the warning at all?

Comment: If I recall correctly, maps' key and value are implemented as a pair of const key and value. You cannot change the key of a given value (that implies reordering, so you can delete and reinsert with a different key), so that makes the `const` part of the `const uint8_t` useless.

Comment: @StoryTeller Goog point! There's also an error 5-0-1 (order of evaluation) on the `==`, which might be resolved with `cend()`, but that's a different issue. (The checker is on our CI server, so I cannot interactively see what happens.)

Comment: TBH, since nothing is const, this seems like a false positive on the checker's part. It seems to think erroneously that `find` will return a `const_iterator`. Can't tell you how to proceed though.

Comment: @Mirko That's my colleague trying lots of different things, so yes, the `const` is redundant, although there might be another MISRA rule that recommends it. I get similar errors in my code without the `const`.

Comment: besides, using a 256-element array will be faster if your map has a lot of items

Comment: Implicit conversion to different underlying type implies some manner of expression other than `==`. Are you sure the problem is in the part you posted and not elsewhere?